# $_POST array is empty when POSTing with C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, php

I've been trying to get some client-server interaction happening with JSON, however, the data that I post to the server is not arriving; the `$_POST` array in my PHP script is empty.

I've just ended up grabbing the WebRequest example straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) and testing that. That still doesn't work. I've also tried just posting some data with HTML form, and that works fine. I'm completely stumped.

When I call `getallheaders()` in my PHP I get

```
OK
array(5) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
    string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ["Host"]=>
    string(9) "localhost"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
    string(2) "54"
  ["Expect"]=>
    string(12) "100-continue"
  ["Connection"]=>
    string(10) "Keep-Alive"
```

though doing a var_dump($_POST) returns array(0)

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Maybe try to post a relevant piece of C# code, so we can see where's the problem. For now I can say just one thing - you're obviously doing "something" wrong :)

Comment: You could setup fiddler as a proxy for your request, that way you can see whats gets transferred, and if its well formed, or show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in MSDN sends a raw string, so PHP doesn't know how to brake it into fields and put it in `$_POST`. You should be able to get that POST data with `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

If you want the data to get to `$_POST`, you need to encode it(the same way you encode it, the same way you encode GET parameters:

```
string postData="fieldName="+System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("The data that goes in the field");
```

As always, if you need multiple fields you need to separate them with `&`s.

Comment: Idan, you're an absolute legend. Worked like a charm, and great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those are just your Headers. You shouldn't expect your POST parameters in the result of getallheaders() call. You're sending *something* as the content-length suggest 54 bytes. Try var dumping $_REQUEST parameter, see if they're being submitted with another method.

Comment: Currently I'm using the example code from the MSDN link above, no changes